# How can I optimize code

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I would like to optimize this code. If you see some stupid things, or you have better way to rewrite this code, please let me know.

```
$event = $eventsTable->getEvent($eventId, ['all']);

foreach ($event['tickets'] as $ticketId => $ticket) {
    $ticket['ticket_id'] = null;
    $ticket['ticket_event_id'] = null;
    array_replace($event['tickets'][$ticketId], array_push($event['tickets'], $ticket));
    unset($event['tickets'][$ticketId]);
}

$form->populate($event);
```

This code works, but I have doubt about technical stuff.

EDIT: My problem was to get ticket from existed events, duplicate data and unset ticket_id and ticket_event_id and save as a new ticket

Comment: Might fit better on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: can you provide a var_dump of `$event['tickets']` and `$event` ?

Comment: @kingkero I didn't know that this site exists. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $event = $eventsTable->getEvent($eventId, ['all']);
    $event2 = $event;
    foreach ($event2['tickets'] as $ticket) {
        $ticket['ticket_id'] = null;
        $ticket['ticket_event_id'] = null;
        $event['tickets'][] = $ticket;
    }
    $form->populate($event);
```

Comment: It does not work. The taken ticketing keys are override and I want to solve this problem in this case